# Display line plot when condition is met in data entry

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a shiny budgeting shiny application that prompts the user to enter data such as what type of expense was spent, the amount, and a description. I would like to display a line plot in the second pannel of the application labeled "Monthly Budget" ONLY when the user has entered at least one data entry where the category is "Savings". I have tried experimenting with things such as hiding/displaying the plot whenever the condition is met, but it seems that I always get a NaN error message with this approach. Thus, I am experimenting with conditionalPanel() in hopes of accomplishing this task. I've noticed similar posts to this one, however this is the first case that I have found where conditionalPanel() deals with data that the user inputs as opposed to a given dataset. In the code below I get the following error message: "Error in: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only".

Here is the code:

```
# Libraries
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(colortools)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
library(formattable)
library(xts)

# Creating Contrasting Colors For Buckets
bucket_colors <- wheel("skyblue", num = 6)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
    # theme = shinytheme("spacelab"),
    shinythemes::themeSelector(),
    
    ## Application Title
    titlePanel("2021 Budgeting & Finances"),
    tags$em("By:"),
    tags$hr(),

    navbarPage("", id = "Budget",
        tabPanel("Data Entry",
                 div(class = "outer",
                # Sidebar Layout 
                sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(
                        selectInput("Name", 
                                    label = "Name:", 
                                    choices = c("","Jack", "Jill")),
                        selectInput("Bucket",
                                    label = "Item Bucket:",
                                    choices = c("","Essential", "Non-Essential", "Savings", "Rent/Bills", "Trip", "Other")),
                        textInput("Item", 
                                  label = "Item Name:",
                                  placeholder = "Ex: McDonald's"),
                        shinyWidgets::numericInputIcon("Amount", 
                                                       "Amount:", 
                                                       value = 0, 
                                                       step = 0.01, 
                                                       min = 0, 
                                                       max = 1000000, 
                                                       icon = list(icon("dollar"), NULL)),
                        dateInput("Date",
                                  label = "Date",
                                  value = Sys.Date(),
                                  min = "2021-05-01",
                                  max = "2022-12-31",
                                  format = "M-d-yyyy"),
                        actionButton("Submit", "Submit", class = "btn btn-primary"),
                        downloadButton("Download", "Download")),
                    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
                    mainPanel(
                       tableOutput("PreviewTable")
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
############ THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR HAPPENS #############
        tabPanel("Monthly Budget",
                 conditionalPanel("output.any(ReactiveDf() == 'Savings') == TRUE ",
                 plotOutput("SavingsPlot")
                 )
########### THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR HAPPENS ##############
        ),
        tabPanel("Budget to Date",
                 tableOutput("YearTable")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    ## SAVE DATA
    # Set Up Empty DF
    df <- tibble("Name" = character(),
                 "Date" = character(),
                 "Category" = character(),
                 "Amount" = numeric(),
                 "Description" = character())
    # DF is made reactive so we can add new lines
    ReactiveDf <- reactiveVal(value = df)
    
    # Add inputs as new data (lines)
    observeEvent(input$Submit, {
        if (input$Bucket == "" | input$Amount == 0 |
            is.na(input$Amount)) {
            return(NULL) 
        } 
        
        else {
            # New lines are packaged together in a DF
            new_lines <- data.frame(Name = as.character(input$Name),
                                    Date = as.character(input$Date),
                                    Category = input$Bucket,
                                    Amount = as.character(input$Amount),
                                    Description = as.character(input$Item))
            
            # change df globally
            df <<-  rbind(df, new_lines)
            
            # ensure amount is numeric
            df <<- df %>%
                mutate("Amount" = as.numeric(Amount))
            
            # Update reactive values
            ReactiveDf(df)
            
            #clear out original inputs now that they are written to df
            updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "Name", selected = "")
            updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "Bucket", selected = "")
            updateNumericInput(session, inputId = "Amount", value = 0)
            updateTextInput(session, inputId = "Item", value = "")
        }
    })
    
    ## Preview Table
    observeEvent(input$Submit, {
    output$PreviewTable <- 
         function(){
            ReactiveDf()[order(ReactiveDf()$Date, decreasing = TRUE),] %>%
            kable("html") %>%
            kable_material(c("striped", "hover")) %>%
            kable_styling("striped", full_width = TRUE) %>%
            column_spec(3, color = "black", background = ifelse(ReactiveDf()[3]=="Essential", "#87CEEB", ifelse(ReactiveDf()[3] == "Non-Essential", "#EBA487", ifelse(ReactiveDf()[3] == "Savings", "#87EBA4", ifelse(ReactiveDf()[3] == "Rent/Bills", "#A487EB", ifelse(ReactiveDf()[3] == "Trip", "#CEEB87", "#EB87CE")))))) %>%
            column_spec(1, color = ifelse(ReactiveDf()[1] == "Ashley", "lightpink", "lightcyan"))
        
         }
########## THIS IS THE LINE PLOT I AM TRYING TO RENDER ##########    
    output$SavingsPlot <- renderPlot({
        savings <- ReactiveDf()[ReactiveDf()$Category == "Savings",]
        savings <- savings[, -c(1,3,5)]
        savings$Date <- as.Date(savings$Date)
        savings$Amount <- as.numeric(savings$Amount)
        
        savings <- as.xts(savings$Amount, order.by = as.Date(savings$Date))
        weekly <- apply.weekly(savings,sum)
        weekly_savings <- as.data.frame(weekly)
        weekly_savings$names <- rownames(weekly_savings)
        rownames(weekly_savings) <- NULL
        colnames(weekly_savings) <- c("Amount", "Date")
        
        Expected <- NULL
        for(i in 1:dim(weekly_savings)[1]){
            Expected[i] <- i * 625
        }
        weekly_savings$Expected <- Expected
        ggplot(weekly_savings, aes(x = Date)) + 
            geom_line(aes(y = Expected), color = "red") +
            geom_line(aes(y = Amount), color = "blue") +
            ggtitle("House Downpayment Savings Over Time") +
            ylab("Dollars") +
            scale_x_date(date_minor_breaks = "2 day") +
            scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::dollar_format())
    })
    })    
########## THIS IS THE LINE PLOT I AM TRYING TO RENDER ##########

    # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
    output$Download <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
            paste("A&J Budgeting ", Sys.Date(),".csv", sep = "")
        },
        content = function(file) {
            write.csv(ReactiveDf(), file, row.names = FALSE)
        }
    )
    
    # use if df new lines have errors
    observeEvent(input$start_over, {
        # change df globally
        df <- tibble("Name" = character(),
                     "Date" = character(),
                     "Expense Category" = character(),
                     "Amount" = numeric(),
                     "Description" = character())
        # Update reactive values to empty out df
        ReactiveDf(df)
    })
    
    ## MONTHLY TABLE
    output$MonthlyTable <- renderTable({
        ReactiveDf()
    })
    
    ## YEAR TO DATE TABLE
    output$YearTable <- renderTable({
        ReactiveDf()
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What about using `validate`? You can put a call to validate in the first part of your call to `renderPlot` to produce a plot only when certain conditions are met - in this case, that there is data in the Savings category. See [help page and examples here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/validate.html)

Answer (score 0):

We can use a condition like `nrow(filter(ReactiveDf(), Category == 'Savings')) > 0` as if `ReactiveDf` is a normal df. Also, when converting the xts object to a df the `Date` column was coerced to character.

app:

```
# Libraries
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(colortools)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
library(formattable)
library(xts)
library(lubridate)

# Creating Contrasting Colors For Buckets
bucket_colors <- wheel("skyblue", num = 6)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  # theme = shinytheme("spacelab"),
  shinythemes::themeSelector(),
  
  ## Application Title
  titlePanel("2021 Budgeting & Finances"),
  tags$em("By:"),
  tags$hr(),
  
  navbarPage("", id = "Budget",
             tabPanel("Data Entry",
                      div(class = "outer",
                          # Sidebar Layout 
                          sidebarLayout(
                            sidebarPanel(
                              selectInput("Name", 
                                          label = "Name:", 
                                          choices = c("","Jack", "Jill")),
                              selectInput("Bucket",
                                          label = "Item Bucket:",
                                          choices = c("","Essential", "Non-Essential", "Savings", "Rent/Bills", "Trip", "Other")),
                              textInput("Item", 
                                        label = "Item Name:",
                                        placeholder = "Ex: McDonald's"),
                              shinyWidgets::numericInputIcon("Amount", 
                                                             "Amount:", 
                                                             value = 0, 
                                                             step = 0.01, 
                                                             min = 0, 
                                                             max = 1000000, 
                                                             icon = list(icon("dollar"), NULL)),
                              dateInput("Date",
                                        label = "Date",
                                        value = Sys.Date(),
                                        min = "2021-05-01",
                                        max = "2022-12-31",
                                        format = "M-d-yyyy"),
                              actionButton("Submit", "Submit", class = "btn btn-primary"),
                              downloadButton("Download", "Download")),
                            # Show a plot of the generated distribution
                            mainPanel(
                              tableOutput("PreviewTable")
                            )
                          )
                      )
             ),
             tabPanel("Monthly Budget",
                       plotOutput("SavingsPlot") 
             ),
             tabPanel("Budget to Date",
                      tableOutput("YearTable")
             )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ## SAVE DATA
  # Set Up Empty DF
  df <- tibble("Name" = character(),
               "Date" = character(),
               "Category" = character(),
               "Amount" = numeric(),
               "Description" = character())
  
  # DF is made reactive so we can add new lines
  ReactiveDf <- reactiveVal(value = df)
  
  # Add inputs as new data (lines)
  observeEvent(input$Submit, {
    if (input$Bucket == "" | input$Amount == 0 |
        is.na(input$Amount)) {
      return(NULL) 
    } 
    
    else {
      # New lines are packaged together in a DF
      new_lines <- data.frame(Name = as.character(input$Name),
                              Date = as.character(input$Date),
                              Category = input$Bucket,
                              Amount = as.character(input$Amount),
                              Description = as.character(input$Item))
      
      # change df globally
      df <<-  rbind(df, new_lines)
      
      # ensure amount is numeric
      df <<- df %>%
        mutate("Amount" = as.numeric(Amount))
      
      # Update reactive values
      ReactiveDf(df)
      
      #clear out original inputs now that they are written to df
      updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "Name", selected = "")
      updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "Bucket", selected = "")
      updateNumericInput(session, inputId = "Amount", value = 0)
      updateTextInput(session, inputId = "Item", value = "")
    }
  })
  
  ## Preview Table
  observeEvent(input$Submit, {
    output$PreviewTable <- 
      function(){
        ReactiveDf()[order(ReactiveDf()$Date, decreasing = TRUE),] %>%
          kable("html") %>%
          kable_material(c("striped", "hover")) %>%
          kable_styling("striped", full_width = TRUE) %>%
          column_spec(3, color = "black", background = ifelse(ReactiveDf()[3]=="Essential", "#87CEEB", ifelse(ReactiveDf()[3] == "Non-Essential", "#EBA487", ifelse(ReactiveDf()[3] == "Savings", "#87EBA4", ifelse(ReactiveDf()[3] == "Rent/Bills", "#A487EB", ifelse(ReactiveDf()[3] == "Trip", "#CEEB87", "#EB87CE")))))) %>%
          column_spec(1, color = ifelse(ReactiveDf()[1] == "Ashley", "lightpink", "lightcyan"))
        
      }
    ########## THIS IS THE LINE PLOT I AM TRYING TO RENDER ##########
    
    if (nrow(filter(ReactiveDf(), Category == 'Savings')) > 0) {
      
      output$SavingsPlot <- renderPlot({
        savings        <- filter(ReactiveDf(), Category == 'Savings')
        savings$Date   <- as.Date(savings$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
        savings$Amount <- as.numeric(savings$Amount)

        savings        <- as.xts(savings$Amount, order.by = savings$Date)
        weekly         <- apply.weekly(savings, sum)
        weekly_savings <- as.data.frame(weekly)
        weekly_savings$names <- rownames(weekly_savings)
        rownames(weekly_savings) <- NULL
        colnames(weekly_savings) <- c("Amount", "Date")

        Expected <- NULL
        for(i in 1:dim(weekly_savings)[1]){
          Expected[i] <- i * 625
        }
        
        weekly_savings$Expected <- Expected
        ggplot(weekly_savings, aes(x = ymd(Date))) +
          geom_line(aes(y = Expected), color = "red") +
          geom_line(aes(y = Amount), color = "blue") +
          ggtitle("House Downpayment Savings Over Time") +
          ylab("Dollars") +
          scale_x_date(date_minor_breaks = "2 day") +
          scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::dollar_format())
        
      }) }
  })    
  ########## THIS IS THE LINE PLOT I AM TRYING TO RENDER ##########
  
  # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
  output$Download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("A&J Budgeting ", Sys.Date(),".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(ReactiveDf(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
  
  # use if df new lines have errors
  observeEvent(input$start_over, {
    # change df globally
    df <- tibble("Name" = character(),
                 "Date" = character(),
                 "Expense Category" = character(),
                 "Amount" = numeric(),
                 "Description" = character())
    # Update reactive values to empty out df
    ReactiveDf(df)
  })
  
  ## MONTHLY TABLE
  output$MonthlyTable <- renderTable({
    ReactiveDf()
  })
  
  ## YEAR TO DATE TABLE
  output$YearTable <- renderTable({
    ReactiveDf()
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```